# installation of package 'rmarkdown' had non-zero exit status

Tags: installation, rstudio, r-markdown

Im trying to update the Rmarkdown package in RStudio but am getting the following error

```
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\foo\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUdFXnp/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_0.9.2.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In utils::install.packages(c("rmarkdown"), repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'rmarkdown' had non-zero exit status
```

My Session Information is below

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252        LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3`
```

I do not have admin rights on my PC in work but have installed other libraries into the mydocuments section of my PC without issue

Comment: Hi, It seems when installing it from the main menu, the package has problems but if i use the `install.packages` method it seems to work OK. Its strange but it seems to work now. Thanks